# Losing selection of list in NavigationView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I am trying to keep the selection to remain highlighted when navigating back from the destination of the `NavigationLink`. This code running on iPhone 14 simulator on iOS 16 deselects the current selection or selects 2 items and the count of selected items at the bottom does not match the highlighted items.

Am I missing something obvious ?

EDIT 1:

- Need to keep `NavigationView` for compatibility to iOS 15
- The issue is the same when using a single selection instead of a `Set`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    struct Ocean: Identifiable, Hashable {
        let name: String
        let id = UUID()
    }

    private var oceans = [
        Ocean(name: "Pacific"),
        Ocean(name: "Atlantic"),
        Ocean(name: "Indian"),
        Ocean(name: "Southern"),
        Ocean(name: "Arctic")
    ]

    @State private var multiSelection = Set<Ocean>()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(oceans, id: \.self, selection: $multiSelection) { ocean in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text(ocean.name)
                    } label: {
                        Text(ocean.name)
                    }
                }
                Text("\(multiSelection.count) selected")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Oceans")
            .toolbar { EditButton() }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationView` is now deprecated, it is best to use `NaviagtionStack`.

To keep the selections highlighted when navigating back from the NavigationLink, add

```
 NavigationLink {...}
     .listRowBackground(multiSelection.contains(ocean) ? Color.red : Color.clear)
```

Comment: Thank you @sumida however I need to keep compatibility to iOS 15 so I cannot use NavigationStack.

Comment: My answer works just as well for me with `NavigationView`. Does this not work for you?

Comment: it does not work better than the default highlight color. I get the same corrupt selection as in my original example/video: 2 items, one being the second last item that was selected and the other one the last selected item. Am I the only one having this behaviour or is it the same for you too?

Comment: I should clarify, I am on MacOS 13.4, using Xcode 14.3 running on ios-16 iPhone.
Using ios-15 may well be the source of your problem.

Comment: The issue manifested originally with the iPhone 14 simulator on iOS 16.4. I have MacOS 13.3 and Xcode 14.3.